# How to pass variable to another function in the sam controller code igniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I need to filter my datatable using nodoc which is the value of input in page before, it has read in my `v_filterdoc` function but can't be read in my datatable function and it becomes null when I use `input->post` so I need to pass the value to my datatable before the value is null

This is my v_filterdoc functionµ

[image]

And this is my Datatable function

[image]

Comment: you need to post code not image community will help you. thanks

Comment: How to get $nodoc variable in document_datatable function?

Comment: you can directly call this method `$this->m_search->datatableDoucment($nodoc);` in your `v_filterdoc` method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have many ways of passing value from one function in the same controller to another function.

1. the ability of any function like this code. `$this->function_name($variable);`
2. you can use session in the first function you must set the session of `$variable` and use it in another function also its available in all function.